# Moving A text 45 pixel up using CSS

Tags: css

I want to move the text **"HOW IS IT"** 45 pixels top, i am not sure what should i add in the policymain class in CSS, Here is my HTML and CSS

```
<style>
.policymain{width:975px; float:left; margin:0px 0 20px 0px; border-bottom:solid 2px #ccc; padding:12px 0 10px 0px}
</style>

<div id="wrapper">
<div class="midbox">
  <div id="content_area">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" align="center">
        <tr> 
          <td>
<div class="policymain"><b><span style="font-size:30px; font-family:'Myriad Pro'; color:#174480;">HOW IS IT</span></b></div>
<br>
<br>
</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
</table>
 </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To move it 45px up from wherever it currently is, you could use `position: relative; top: -45px;` or `position: absolute; margin-top: -45px;` If you want it 45px from the top of the page, use `position: absolute; top: 45px;`